# Use a dynamic number of buttons with Elm

Tags: elm

I would like to create some buttons whose number will vary with user actions (one per value in a list or array)).

I'm able to create the buttons but not to know in `update` which one was pressed.

For instance, in the following reduced code, how can I increment the value in `data` corresponding to the pressed button?

```
module Main exposing (..)

import Html exposing (..)
import Html.Events exposing (..)
import Array exposing (..)

main =
    Html.program
        { init = init
        , view = view
        , update = update
        , subscriptions = subscriptions
        }

-- MODEL

type alias Model =
    { data : Array Int
    }

init : ( Model, Cmd Msg )
init =
    ( Model (fromList [ 11, 22, 33 ]), Cmd.none )

-- UPDATE

type Msg
    = Play  -- or Play Int ?


update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        Play ->
            ( model, Cmd.none )

-- VIEW

view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    div [] (Array.map viewButton model.data |> toList)

viewButton : Int -> Html Msg
viewButton v =
    div [] [ button [ onClick Play ] [ text (toString v) ] ]

subscriptions : Model -> Sub Msg
subscriptions model =
    Sub.none
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track with your comment about `Msg` maybe having a `Play Int` constructor. The way we usually handle this in Elm is by carrying around the index. You can use `Array.indexedMap` in the `view` function to pull both the index and data.

Here is an updated version of the relevant parts of your code with only a few changes that increments each button on click:

```elm
type alias Model =
    { data : Array Int
    }

-- UPDATE
type Msg
    = Play Int

update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        Play idx ->
            ( { model | data = incrementAt idx model.data }, Cmd.none )

incrementAt : Int -> Array Int -> Array Int
incrementAt idx arr =
    let
        cur =
            Maybe.withDefault 0 (get idx arr)
    in
        set idx (cur + 1) arr

-- VIEW
view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    div [] (Array.indexedMap viewButton model.data |> toList)

viewButton : Int -> Int -> Html Msg
viewButton idx v =
    div [] [ button [ onClick (Play idx) ] [ text (toString v) ] ]
```

This snippet is available on [runelm.io](https://runelm.io/c/yre).